# Find real position of an ImageView

Tags: java, android, position, imageview

I would like to find the real position of an `ImageView` drawable. Currently it returns 0, because the `ImageView` is resized by relative layout. But the drawable inside the image view is not fill all in the relative layout. It fills the full width, and it is centered vertically with empty space at the top and bottom of it.

```
    <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout_main"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/drawable"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please see the attached screenshot. I am searching for x and y of red rectangle and the width, height of it.

[image]

Comment: Did u try the  imageView.getDrawable().getBounds(). left /right/bottom/top value ..??

Comment: It returns 0,0 or parent position

Comment: if its match parent width and parent is full screen width the start will be 0 0 only..??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to wait until the Views have been measured. You can use an `OnGlobalLayoutListener`.

```
imageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        int height = imageView.getHeight();
        int width = imageView.getWidth();
        int x = imageView.getLeft();
        int y = imageView.getTop();

        // don't forget to remove the listener to prevent being called again 
        // by future layout events:
        imageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
    }
});
```

Because your `ImageView` fills the entire screen, it will probably give the device's width as width, and the window height as height. To get the actual width and height of the image inside the `ImageView`, set the `RelativeLayout`'s height to `match_parent` and set the `ImageView`'s height to `wrap_content`, and set the `ImageView`'s `layout_gavity` to `center_vertical`.

Comment: Thanks for Your answer I will check it ASAP and reply how it works

Comment: Sorry it returns bad values left is properly because it is 0, but top has bad value

Comment: What does top return?

Comment: nearly 200 for 3 images but it should be over 400

Comment: If you want the top of the drawable inside the ImageView, you could call: imageView.getDrawable().getBounds().top to get relative top, or imageView.getTop() +  imageView.getDrawable().getBounds().top for absolute top, after you've waited for the view to be laid out of course.

Answer (score 3):

I think i have the solution:

You have to override the method onWindowFocusChanged of the activity where you are
to be sure that the views have been inflated:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    int array[] = new int[2];
    image.getLocationOnScreen(array);
}
```

When this finishes, in array varaible you will have the correct coordinates, I hope.

PS: image is your ImageView.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: Here **drawLeft** is **X** value and  **drawTop** is **Y**  value.

```
ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);
Rect rt = image.getDrawable().getBounds();

int drawLeft = rt.left;
int drawTop = rt.top;
int drawRight = rt.right;
int drawBottom = rt.bottom;
```

You can get the **height = drawBottom - drawTop** and **width = drawRight - drawLeft** .

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
int[] imageCordinates = new int[2];
imageView.getLocationOnScreen(imageCordinates);

int x = imageCordinates[0];
int y = imageCordinates[1];
```

// this code will return you coordinates of image on screen whenever you want

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the `getTranslationX()` and `getTranslationY()` methods to get the real coordinates of your view. and If these methods return you 0 values, attach a click handler in the view that you interested , and inside the onClick call the methods above and also getWidth, and getHeight.

Comment: Thanks for Your answer I will check it ASAP and reply how it works

Comment: Your answer still returns 0,0

Comment: and what about the getWidth and hetHeight methods? What are they returning if you call them inside the listener?

Comment: getWidth and getHeight after @Mark Buikema comment returns properly values, but still I need x and y

Answer (score 0):

The question is: What do you want to achieve? (I mean, why do you need to get the empty space to the front?)

Your `ImageView` is resized to fill the parent, that's why you get `0` from the recommondations. So your `ImageView` should be as big as the picture. Change the height of your `Imageview` to `wrap_content` and tell your image to resize as big as possible. If I didn't make a mistake, your `RelativeLayout` should be green and you should see your Image in the center (if Image is smaller than `parent_width`, than you should see the red background to the left and right).

```
 <RelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/relative_layout_main"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light" //green background for debugging
 >

<ImageView
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light" //red background for debugging
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"     //change hieght to content
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"     //center in parent
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"            //scale image to fit center
    android:src="@drawable/drawable"/>
```

And now you should get your `ImageView` position as @Neha suggested

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a button and click the button. Inside onclick() method get the imageView's height and width. Everytime you are getting zero because you haven't done anything with the screen. Atleast you have pass some event and handle event.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I need this position to add other elements, not for onClick method